# Как расположить два объекта в ряд, что-бы второй центрировался относительно свободной части экрана

Tags: html

[image: Как должен выглядеть сайт]

Как расположить два div'a на сайте, таким же образом как на картинке? Без использования "float"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете для правого блока задать `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
.wrapper
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}

.left
{
  width: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.right
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```